# How do I run my Selenium Side Runner in Command Prompt? Where do I have to save the .side file? I have saved .side file in Downloads folder

Tags: selenium-side-runner

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads>selenium-side-runner \Users\Admin\Downloads\Amazon.side
 FAIL  ../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/dist/main.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    No matching projects found, supplied filepaths: \Users\Admin\Downloads\Amazon.side

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/main.test.ts:86:9)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.042 s
Ran all test suites within paths "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-side-runner\dist\main.test.js".


Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.042 s
Ran all test suites within paths "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-side-runner\dist\main.test.js".
```